# jsonで FileNotFoundError: この二つの差はなんですか？

Tags: python, pytorch

片方は読み込めるのですが、もう片方は読み込めません。この二つの違いは何でしょうか？
コード2 は https://github.com/graykode/ALBERT-Pytorch のコードを試そうとしました。
コード1 はエラーが出た部分を切り出した。

コード1 動く

```
import json

json.load(open('config/pretrain.json'))
print("aaaa")
```

コード2 動かない

```
class Config(NamedTuple):
    """ Hyperparameters for training """
    seed: int = 3431 # random seed
    batch_size: int = 8
    lr: int = 5e-5 # learning rate
    n_epochs: int = 10 # the number of epoch
    # `warm up` period = warmup(0.1)*total_steps
    # linearly increasing learning rate from zero to the specified value(5e-5)
    warmup: float = 0.1
    save_steps: int = 100 # interval for saving model
    total_steps: int = 100000 # total number of steps to train

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, file): # load config from json file
        return cls(**json.load(open(file, "r")))
```

エラーメッセージ
file変数（ディレクトリ）がコード1と同じなのは確認しています。

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pretrain.py", line 285, in <module>
        main(args=args)
      File "pretrain.py", line 211, in main
        cfg = train.Config.from_json(args.train_cfg)
      File "C:\Users\PC_User\newAI2022y08y23d\project\ALBERT-Pytorch-master\train.py",         line 32, in from_json
        return cls(**json.load(open(file, "r")))
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'config/pretrain.json'"
```

Comment: int32_t さん回答を基に、全然関係無い(該当ディレクトリ/ファイルが存在しない)ディレクトリ上でコード１そのままと、その`json.load(open('config/pretrain.json'))`のパス名を`"`で囲んで`json.load(open("'config/pretrain.json'"))`に変更したものを実行すると、違うエラーメッセージになるので、int32_t さん回答が合っているでしょう。ちなみに実行時のカレント作業ディレクトリが何処かも`import os; print(os.getcwd())`等で確かめておいた方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'config/pretrain.json'"`

エラーメッセージがこの通りならば、ファイル名前後に不要な `'` が付いているように見えます。